Embedding logo image in outlook 2021 message
Our ERP can send pdf documents (such as purchase order,invoice etc.) by mail directly creating a outlook message with text and relating pdf attachment.
This worked fine since 10 and more years and also today with the last outlook versions.
The problem is that a customer wants to include the factory logo image in the above automatic email messages.
Then I create the message in html format using the CID for the image.
This works fine with outlook 2007 sender even with the outlook 2021 recipient but fails with outlook 2021 sender, we see the logo image in the message sent but the recipient (O2021 or O2007) do not see the image but the blank space with the red X (the image appear as attachment).
Analyzing the html received from outlook 2021 sender I see:
img src="cid:64020EBE8CEE9B41AE28BBDD7F09B52E@eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com" width="383"
where in O2007 sender (received with O2021,O2007 do not care) I have:
img src='cid:xxxxxmail.jpg' width=383
Is clear that the problem is represented by outlook 2021 in which the image embedding is close to be forbidden for security problems.
Any idea to solve this issue?
Having these restriction in 2024 is astonishing.
Thank You.

You must set the Content-ID MIME header (or the PR_ATTACH_CONTENTID MAPI property depending on how you create messages) on the attachment to the matching value ("64020EBE8CEE9B41AE28BBDD7F09B52E@eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com").
